# ARM assembly, comparing signed values

Tags: assembly, arm, arm7

I have a very simple problem but it is driving me up the wall, would you please help me?

Here is the question: how do I compare two signed byte values in ARM assembly? This is what I tried:

```
ldrsb r1, [r0], #1
ldrsb r2, [r0]
cmp r1, r2
```

r0 is loaded with the address of a list of byte values like 10, -1, 123. should ldrsb not sig extend when loading a negative number? I am lost

**EDIT:**

well we're supposed to write a program that sorts of a list of signed byte values (using bubblesort). I can figure out how to do that, it's just that I don't understand the actual comparison (or its result). This is my code so far:

```
.global main

.section .data
  myNumbers: .byte 183, 374, -113, -1, 10, 101, -3, -54, 9, 7
  myNumbersEnd:

.section .text
  main:

  loop:
    mov r4, #0
    ldr r0, =myNumbers
    ldr r3, =myNumbersEnd

inner_loop:
    ldrsb r1, [r0], #1  
    ldrsb r2, [r0]  
    cmp r1, r2

    strgtb r1, [r0]
    strgtb r2, [r0, #-1]
    movgt r4, #1 @ r4 = swapped = true

    cmp r0, r3
    bne inner_loop

    cmp r4, #1
    beq loop @ keep going
exit:
    b exit
.end
```

Maybe I should add that i am not running this code on actual ARM hardware, but on ARMSim#, a simulator for the ARM7TDMI processor: http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/index.html

Comment: ldrsb will do sign extension. Maybe you should write a bit more about your code. Everything you've shown so far is correct, so what does not work? Either your r0 is not setup correctly or you're using the wrong conditional predicates afterwards.

Comment: You still don't tell what the actual problem is. What are the symptoms? Have you tried stepping through the program with the debugger?

Comment: Watch out for the cmp, which may not treat signed values as signed

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll try to break that down.

1. `r4` contains "Did we swap anything?"
2. `r0` and `r3` contain start and end of the input data

   ```
   loop:
     mov r4, #0
     ldr r0, =myNumbers
     ldr r3, =myNumbersEnd
   ```
3. Load and signextend `r1` with the byte pointed to by `r0`, update `r0` to `r0+1`
4. Also load and signextend `r2` from the updated `r0`
5. Compare both values, this essentially is `r1-r2` depending the result flags are updated.

   ```
   inner_loop:
       ldrsb r1, [r0], #1  
       ldrsb r2, [r0]  
       cmp r1, r2
   ```
6. If r1 was greater than r2, store the values in swapped order
7. Also set the swapped flag (r4)

   ```
       strgtb r1, [r0]
       strgtb r2, [r0, #-1]
       movgt r4, #1 @ r4 = swapped = true
   ```
8. Compare our current pointer in `r0` to the end pointer in `r3`
9. Unless they're equal do the next byte

   ```
       cmp r0, r3
       bne inner_loop
   ```
10. Check if we swapped anything, start over if we did.

    ```
        cmp r4, #1
        beq loop @ keep going
    ```

The key point here is the comparison. As already stated, cmp does an op1-op2 throws away the result, but sets flags according to the result, these flags are:
N = tempresult[31] (Indicating that the MSB is set, for signed values that means the result is signed.
Z = tempresult == 0 (Will be 1 when both values are equal)
C = tempresult[31] != op1[31] (Used for unsigned compares and means op1 < op2)
V = op1[31] != op2[31] && op1[31] != tempresult[31] (Something like carry for signed values)

Next your strgtb first uses the flags to see if it really needs to be executed, the condition is `gt` which translates into:

```
Z == 0 && N == V
```

If the condition is true, the instruction will be executed, same for the next two instructions.

FYI, your dataset contains invalid data

```
  myNumbers: .byte 183, 374, -113, -1, 10, 101, -3, -54, 9, 7
```

183 and 374 might cause confusion. A valid SIGNED 8-bit value is between -128 and 127. Your code will evaluate 183 as a signed value.